# In Python how to convert a string to a date and check if it is earlier than 5 mins

Tags: python

I have a string coming in as 5/4/2017 2:13:04 PM
It is in utc timezone. I need to check if it is earlier than 5 mins. So I tried the following code.

```
statustime="""5/4/2017 2:13:04 PM"""
statustimefrm= datetime.strptime(statustime, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p") 
print "Input time "+str(statustimefrm)
print "Current time "+str(datetime.utcnow())
if statustimefrm < datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds = -300):
    print "disconnected longer than 5 mins"
else:
   print "just disconnected wait"
```

The output is

```
Input time 2017-05-04 02:13:04
Current time 2017-05-04 14:16:23.147151
disconnected longer than 5 mins
```

when it is converting

```
statustimefrm= datetime.strptime(statustime, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p")
```

looks like it is not taking the PM into account. When looking at the docs %p is for AM/PM. So why is it not working?

Comment: Where is the string coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your `%H` into `%I`:

```
statustimefrm= datetime.strptime(statustime, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

When you use `strptime` `%p` will only work if `%I` is used in the hour field.

Comment: Does this turn it into a 12 hour display?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to check if a difference is greater, and you're checking it, say, less than every hour, could you just check a few characters from that string?

```
statustime="""5/4/2017 2:13:04 PM"""

if abs(int(statustime[11:13]))>=5:
    print "disconnected longer than 5 mins"
else:
   print "just disconnected wait"
```

You'll need to put a sum in there eg statustime-current time.
This may just be beginner naiivety, but seems like a simpler solution?

Comment: what if the program is run the next day in the AM, then it would say just disconnected when it has been disconnected for a day

Comment: That's why I said *if* you're checking less than every hour. Which allows you to just take the difference between the minutes, as opposed to taking the hour into account (eg 343pm, 443pm). If the checker was reset by a detected status change, and checks with a frequency of, say, ten minutes, you won't have an issue: 1142pm, 1207am=>42-7 is greater than 5.

Comment: I suppose if you needed to you could do a similar check on the date elements of the strings, and on to check the year also, but that would be much longer. Looks like a better answer was found though :)